# Google BigQuery nested select subquery in cross join

Tags: subquery, google-bigquery, cross-join

I have the following code:

```
SELECT ta.application as koekkoek, ta.ipc, ipc_count/ipc_tot as ipc_share, t3.sfields FROM (
  select t1.appln_id as application, t1.ipc_subclass_symbol as ipc, count(t2.appln_id) as ipc_count, sum(ipc_count) over (PARTITION BY application) as ipc_tot
    FROM temp.tls209_small t1
    CROSS JOIN 
   (SELECT appln_id, FROM temp.tls209_small group by appln_id )  t2 
      where t1.appln_id = t2.appln_id
        GROUP BY application, ipc
      ) as ta
  CROSS JOIN thesis.ifris_ipc_concordance t3
  WHERE ta.ipc LIKE t3.ipc+'%'
    AND ta.ipc NOT LIKE t3.not_ipc+'%'
    AND t3.not_appln_id NOT IN 
       (SELECT ipc_subclass_symbol from temp.tls209_small t5 where t5.appln_id = ta.application)
```

Giving the folllowing error:
`Field 'ta.application' not found.`

I have tried numerous notations for the field, but BigQuery doesn't seem to recognize any reference to other tables in the subquery.

The purpose of the code is as to assign new technology classifications to records based on a concordance table:

I have got two tables:
One large table with application id's, classifications and some other stuff `tls209_small`:
[image: tls209_small]

And a concordance table with some exception rules `ifris_ipc_concordance`:
[image: ifris_ipc_concordance]

In the end I need to assign the `sfields` label for each row in `tls209` (300 million rows). The rules are that `ipc_class_symbol+'%'` from the first table should be like `ipc`in the second table, but not like `not_ipc`.
In addition, the `not_appln_id` value, if present, should not be associated with the same appln_id in the first table.

So a small example, say this is the input of the query:

```
appln_id | ipc_class_symbol
1        | A1
1        | A2
1        | A3
1        | C3

sfields | ipc | not_ipc | not_appln_id
X       | A   | A2      | null
Y       | A   | null    | A3
```

appln_id 1 should get two times sfields X because ipc=A, not_ipc matches A1 and A3. 
Y should not be assigned at all as A3 occurs in appln_id 1.

In the results, I also need the share of the `ipc_class_symbol` for a single application (1 for 328100001, 0.5 for 32100009 etc.)

Without the last condition (`AND t3.not_appln_id NOT IN (SELECT ipc_subclass_symbol from temp.tls209_small t5 where t5.appln_id = ta.application)` ) the query works fine: 
[image: results]

Any suggestions on how to get the subquery to recognize the application id (ta.application), or other ways to introduce the last condition to the query?

I realize my explanation of the problem may not be very straightforward, so if anything is not clear please indicate so, I'll try to clarify the issues.

Comment: The problem was solved by  a different approach, as elaborated [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30355055/unexpected-behaviour-of-google-bigquery-where-not-list-contains-string/30355559#30355559)

Answer (score 1):

The query you're performing is doing an anti-join.  You can re-write this as an explicit join, but it is a little verbose:

```
SELECT * 
FROM [x.z] as z
LEFT OUTER JOIN EACH [x.y] as y ON y.appln_id = z.application
WHERE y.not_appln_id is NULL
```

Comment: @Guus the query runs distributed, and simply doesn't recognize a table value, as that part of the query internally could be executed by a different cluster. Does this help?

Comment: thanks, it does help, clearly the approach I took is not feasible, but the solution you suggested does not work because the value of `not_appln_id` should also be compared to all values `ipc_class_symbol` for the `appln_id` or `application` in question. I added an example to my question hope this makes it more clear.

Comment: If you add to the ON line of the join, doesn't work that way?

Answer (score 1):

A working solution for the problem was achieved by first generating a table my matching only the `ipc_class_symbol` from the first table, to the `ipc` column of the second, but also including the `not_ipc`, and `not_appln_id` columns from the second. In addition, a list of all ipc class labels assigned to each appln_id was added using the `GROUP_CONCAT` method.

Finally, with help from [Pentium10](https://stackoverflow.com/users/243782/pentium10), the resulting table was filtered based on the exeption rules as also discussed in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30355055/unexpected-behaviour-of-google-bigquery-where-not-list-contains-string/30355559#30355559).

In the final query, the GROUP BY and JOIN arguments needed EACH modifiers to allow the large tables to be processed:

```
SELECT application as appln_id, ipc as ipc_class, ipc_share, sfields as ifris_class FROM (
  SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT ta.application as application, ta.ipc as ipc, ipc_count/ipc_tot as ipc_share, t3.sfields as sfields, t3.ipc as yes_ipc, t3.not_ipc as not_ipc, t3.not_appln_id as exclude, t4.classes as other_classes FROM (
      SELECT t1.appln_id as application, t1.ipc_class_symbol as ipc, count(t2.appln_id) as ipc_count, sum(ipc_count) over (PARTITION BY application) as ipc_tot
        FROM thesis.tls209_appln_ipc t1

        FULL OUTER JOIN EACH
          (SELECT appln_id, FROM thesis.tls209_appln_ipc GROUP EACH BY appln_id )  t2 
            ON t1.appln_id = t2.appln_id
             GROUP EACH BY application, ipc
          ) AS ta


        LEFT JOIN EACH (
          SELECT appln_id, GROUP_CONCAT(ipc_class_symbol) as classes FROM [thesis.tls209_appln_ipc] 
            GROUP EACH BY appln_id) t4
        ON ta.application = t4.appln_id

        CROSS JOIN  thesis.ifris_ipc_concordance t3
        WHERE ta.ipc CONTAINS t3.ipc
  ) as tx
   WHERE (not ipc contains not_ipc or not_ipc is null) 
   AND (not other_classes contains exclude or exclude is null or other_classes is null)
)
```