# unexpected behaviour of Google BigQuery WHERE NOT list CONTAINS string

Tags: sql, google-bigquery, contains

I have a small example table `temp.ty`: 
[image: data]
From this table I want to only extract the rows where `ipc` is not present in `not_ipc` (and where `exclude` is not present in `other_classes`), which seems rather straigtforward. Yet the following query returns zero results:

```
SELECT * FROM temp.ty where not ipc contains not_ipc
```

If I repclace `not_ipc` with for example `'G01N 33'` it doesn't work either yet if I replace `not_ipc` with `'G01N'` it works just fine.

I have tried variations with wildcards and LIKE operations as well as the STRING() function, but so far I have not been able to manage.
I have a strong feeling I am missing something, but I cant figure it out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a sample query:

```
select * from
(select 'G01N 33/55' as ipc, 'G01N 34' as not_ipc),
(select 'G01N 33/55' as ipc, 'G01N 33' as not_ipc),
(select 'G01N 33/55' as ipc, string(null) as not_ipc)
where not ipc contains not_ipc or not_ipc is null
```

this returns:

```
+-----+------------+---------+---+
| Row |    ipc     | not_ipc |   |
+-----+------------+---------+---+
|   1 | G01N 33/55 | G01N 34 |   |
|   2 | G01N 33/55 | null    |   |
+-----+------------+---------+---+
```

Here is another one:

```
select * from
(select 'G01N 33/55' as ipc, 'G01N 33' as not_ipc, 'C08K 3/08' as exclude, 'C08K 3/08,C08K 77/02' as other_classes),
(select 'G01N 33/55' as ipc, 'G01N 34' as not_ipc, string(null) as exclude, 'C08K 3/08,C08K 77/02' as other_classes),
(select 'G01N 33/55' as ipc, 'G01N 33' as not_ipc, string(null) as exclude, string(null) as other_classes),
(select 'G01N 33/55' as ipc, 'G01N 36' as not_ipc, string(null) as exclude, string(null) as other_classes),
(select 'G01N 33/55' as ipc, string(null) as not_ipc, 'C08K 3/08' as exclude, string(null) as other_classes)
where (not ipc contains not_ipc or not_ipc is null) and (not other_classes contains exclude or exclude is null or other_classes is null)
```

returns:

```
+-----+------------+---------+-----------+----------------------+---+
| Row |    ipc     | not_ipc |  exclude  |    other_classes     |   |
+-----+------------+---------+-----------+----------------------+---+
|   1 | G01N 33/55 | G01N 34 | null      | C08K 3/08,C08K 77/02 |   |
|   2 | G01N 33/55 | G01N 36 | null      | null                 |   |
|   3 | G01N 33/55 | null    | C08K 3/08 | null                 |   |
+-----+------------+---------+-----------+----------------------+---+
```

Comment: @Guus ok you should mark it that too as resolved then.